# Is it possible to use CryptUnprotectData in classic ASP code

Tags: asp-classic, cryptography, capicom

I am aware of capicom.dll but I don't see `CryptUnprotectData` in its interfaces.

Is `CryptUnprotectData` supported by capicom.dll?

If not, is there some way I can access this function from a vbscript or a classic asp webpage?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Set EncryptedData = Server.CreateObject("CAPICOM.EncryptedData")